# Ist "vorm Fahrrad gefallen" korrekt, wie hier verwendet von tagesschau.de?

Tags: preposition

Auf [der Webseite tagesschau.de](https://www.tagesschau.de/ausland/amerika/usa-joe-biden-101.html) steht:

> schließlich sei Biden erst vor kurzem vorm Fahrrad gefallen.

[Laut wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/vorm) ist *vorm* Umgangssprache für "vor dem", aber auch "vor dem Fahrrad gefallen" kommt mir seltsam vor; ich würde denken, "von dem Fahrrad gefallen" oder "vom Fahrrad gefallen", es sei denn, er war zu Fuß und ist gefallen, als er vor einem Fahrrad stand oder lief?  Google Search bietet nur wenige Ergebnisse für "vorm Fahrrad gefallen".

Ist "vorm Fahrrad gefallen" hier korrekt, oder macht tagesschau.de hier einen Fehler?

Comment: Falls Biden zu Fuß unterwegs war, wäre allenfalls "vors Fahhrad gefallen" möglich.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alle Ausführungen in der Frage sind korrekt.

Es muss heißen ***vom** Fahrrad gefallen*.

Tagesschau.de macht hier einen Schreibfehler.